# Plants and Specialised Cells

Tags: cell-biology, eukaryotic-cells

Would the number of specialised cells in a leaf decrease if the plant was located in a shadier area? I thought it would decrease as there would be no need to store as much food in the plant and that the plants usually take nutrients from the surrounding environment. However, I don't know if this is correct; it would be nice if someone could provide a better/correct deduction or explanation defining the difference in the number of specialised cells in the leaf in shadier areas.